# Amazon Web Services - RDS Configuration

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS tools for deploy a simple application.

I have a RDS instance (Oracle) and it is working.  (I can access to it from SQL Developer in my local computer)

By other side, I built in Eclipse a simple application in jsp that loops over a table in my Oracle instance (above metioned) and shows the values in the screen.

Test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="dbconnection.DataSource"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tercera Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
DataSource ods = new DataSource();  
Connection conn=ods.connect();
out.println (ods.getUserName(conn));
// Close the connection
conn.close();
conn = null;
%>

</body>
</html>
```

DataSource.java

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class DataSource
{

  public String getUserName(Connection conn)
       throws SQLException
  {
    // Create a Statement
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();
    String str="";
    // Select the ENAME column from the EMP table
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery ("select USER from dual");

    // Iterate through the result and print the employee names
    while (rset.next ())
      str= "User name is " + rset.getString (1);

    // Close the RseultSet
    rset.close();
    rset =  null;

    // Close the Statement
    stmt.close();
    stmt = null;

    return (str);
  }

  public Connection connect() throws SQLException{
        // Create a OracleDataSource instance explicitly
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();

        // Set the user name, password, driver type and network protocol
        ods.setDriverType("thin");
        ods.setServerName("xxxxxx");
        ods.setDatabaseName("oracledb");
        ods.setPortNumber(1521);
        ods.setUser("xxxxxx");
        ods.setPassword("xxxxxxx");

        Connection conn = ods.getConnection();

        return (conn);

  }
}
```

Once this app is deployed in Apache Tomcat server (localhost), everything Works ok and the value is shown in the screen.

[image: everything ok]

However, once this app is deployed over Elastic BeanStalk service (using AWS toolkit for Eclipse), the web page takes too long for loading, and finally nothing appear (page in blank). In fact, it does not shows errors either.

[image: nothing appears]

I was debugging line by line, and everything goes well untill the line :

```
Connection conn=ods.connect();
```

I think is something related to the configuration of my RDS Oracle instance. but Im not sure. it is how it is configured.

[image: mi aws rds Oracle instance]

Do you have any idea?

Many Thanks

Comment: Is the server name you've hidden in your connect method the same as the endpoint in your image? Does the connection attempt time out, or get some other error? First thought is that it sounds like a firewall issue, but would have to be outbound from the AWS instance hosting the JSP?

Comment: Yes. the server name is the same as the end point in the image.  When i execute, there are no errors, just takes aprox. 1 minute and then shows a blank page. and trying to answer your last question, yes, as I understand, i can connect to de RDS Oracle instance just by giving user,pass,host,port,db name.. It is what i did for connecting from my local computer to the database (usiing Apache Tomcat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured that the RDS Instance and the Elastic Beanstalk have the appropriate security groups?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html#using-features.managing.ec2.securitygroups

Comment: No I hadnt, I have just configure it. it Works now!! Thank you.

Comment: Hey no worries, glad you figured it out. You can also tighten up that inbound security group for the RDS instance. Instead of 0.0.0.0/0, you can just put the security group of the Elastic Beanstalk configuration. If you type 's' the AWS console should auto populate choices for you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!.

Need to configure Security Groups.

My RDS Instace had only one inbound ip (it was my local computer, thats why it worked from Apache Tomcat Server). For allowing all ip's you must specify 0.0.0.0/0 as ip.

:)